# Load variable values from the given .tfvars file got an error to many arguments

Tags: terraform, devops

I run terraform plan commnad with apllo.tfvars file

`terraform plan -var-file=apllo.tfvars`

│ Error: Too many command line arguments

│ To specify a working directory for the plan, use the global -chdir flag.

**my variable.tf**

```
variable "user" {
    type = string
}

# number variable 
variable "age" {
    type = number
}
```

**apllo.tfvars**

```
user = "AWSUSER"
age = 222
```

**output.tf**

```
output "name" {
  value = "hello ${var.user}"
}

output "age" {
    value = "age ${var.age}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Powershell for running Terraform, try specifying the `.tfvar` file using single or double quotes, such as:

```sh
terraform plan -var-file="apollo.tfvar"
```